# Find and delete wrong node in a BST in C

Tags: c, algorithm, pointers, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I have a C problem which i need to check if a given Tree is a Binary Search Tree or not and then find which node is incorrect and delete it (from the problem definition, it will always be just one wrong node). For instance:

```
       10
       |
       |
 9          12
 |          |
 |          |
7  3       11  14
```

In this tree, element 3 is incorrect and should be deleted. In case of given tree is already a BST, algorithm should do nothing. I'm trying to adapt a solution from CodeForGeeks which verifies if a tree is a BST or not to instead returning a boolean, returning a pointer for the node which is wrong, but this isn't working well. Here's the method i came up with:

```
NODE* verifyBinaryTree(NODE* root, NO** previous){
    if(node != NULL){
        NODE* left= verifyBinaryTree(root->left, previous);
        if(left != NULL){
            return left;
        }

        if(*previous && root->data <= (*previous)->data) return root;

        *previous = root;

        return(verifyBinaryTree(root->right, previous));
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

I would enjoy if someone could help me to find the right logic behind this problem.

Comment: I think the function needs a `maxValue` and a `minValue` to check against. Any time the code follows a left branch, the `maxValue` needs to be updated. Following a right branch updates the `minValue`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easy way to approach this problem . If you do ***inorder traversal*** on a valid BST , you will get the nodes sorted in ***increasing order*** .

You can do this inorder traversal and after storing them serially in a data structure (perhaps array) , check if the adjacent elements are not in **increasing order** . If you find such elements , you need to delete them .

Comment: There is a problem with this approach. Consider the tree from the original post, the result linked list from the inorder transversal would be: 7 9 3 10 11 12 14, it would be easy to identify 3 as the wrong node. But now think in the original tree, but instead 3 as the wrong element, the 7 would be wrong (let's say 7 would be 16). The resulted linked list would be: 16 9 15 20 22 24 26. How could i identify the wrong element, 16 and not the 9, in this case?

Comment: I think that it depends on your definition of what is wrong . You never defined in your post as the wrong node to be just according to it's parent : )  You can consider either of them to be wrong